# How do you get access to the current filtered trait in xUnit

Tags: selenium, xunit, xunit.net

In xUnit, is there a way to get access to the current trait filter during the test execution? For example, during our build process we setup a task to run our tests with a given trait (i.e. browser type). In our test setup code, I would like to know if the requested test run has received a trait filter, so I can use that to determine what Selenium web driver to use for that test run.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Have not you looked in the source? I'd have a quick peek as it might be easier to find than you think - xUnit is a very clean codebase.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ruben. I had a look through the source code, including the TraitHelper class, but didn't see a way to get access to the current trait filter during the test run execution. I therefore decided to take a different approach and have my build process set an environment variable prior to running the tests.

Comment: Good thinking - legwork done, if you can describe in a bit more depth opening a quick issue on the xunit github to see if it there are any other ideas around this may be worth doing. Also there was [a recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38952833/11635) wrt passing env vars/context to xUnit that might be worth reading.